# How to improve XMLDocument performance while passing parameter to Load & Save

Tags: c#, xml

I am try to improve the performance of my web and desktop application my both these web and win form application is use to read and write the xml file. but I am still confuse what i use to impreve the performance of application.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(fileStream);
xmlDoc.Save(fileStream);
```

so what type of parameter i pass to load and save function ie it may be filestream object or it may  only file name. so that application performance is improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recomend using the `XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();` since there is a better and more cleaner aproach to use

`XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument()`; provides easier implementation and overall future changes

then you can use

```
doc.Load("PurchaseOrder.xml");
```

or if you are downloading from web I would suggest to use Async with weblcient

```
WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
wclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("url of your xml"));
wclient.DownloadStringCompleted += FilesIsCompleted;
private void FilesIsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, your performance bottleneck is with Xml loading, if so try to put it in a different thread

or

if the document is too big and you are trying to load only partial items try something like
[this](http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/streaming-into-linq-to-xml-using-c-custom-iterators-and-xmlreader/)

Comment: Just realized, that jon skeet referred the same article for a different thread, so should be a very reliable one :)